# Using bgcolor in td

Tags: html

I came across something interesting. When I put `bgcolor="someColor"` for a `td`I get green?!

Can anyone explain this phenomena or am I just not getting it right?

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor="someColor">HIt LOL</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Double checked to make sure there's no css files that assigns `someColor` to green?

Comment: Type 'mahadevan', you'll get black lol.